# How do I subdivide a column in a 4-column YUI grid.css layout?

Tags: css, yui, yui-grids

I have a YUI grid that gives me 4 uneven columns:

```
  <div class="yui-gc">
    <div class="yui-gd first">
      <div class="yui-u first">Reason</div>
      <div class="yui-u">Scope</div>
    </div>
    <div class="yui-g">
      <div class="yui-u first">Related</div>
      <div class="yui-u">Product</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Below that I want to have 5 columns, with the extra one coming from breaking the Scope column 2/3, 1/3. The closest I can get is 1/2, 1/2 under Scope:

```
  <div class="yui-gc">
    <div class="yui-gd first">
      <div class="yui-u first">reasons</div>
      <div class="yui-g"> <!-- split Scope column -->
        <div class="yui-u first">questions</div>
        <div class="yui-u">answers</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="yui-g">
      <div class="yui-u first">stuff</div>
      <div class="yui-u">products</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

It seems like changing the div marked `<!-- split Scope column -->` to `<div class="yui-gc">` should do the trick, but it doesn't.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as i'm sure you've already tried, the .yui-g for your  div should be a .yui-gc.  it also needs to be either wrapped in a yui-u or have an yui-u class in addition to the yui-gc.   however the yui css file trips on itself at this point.  The .yui-gd div.first rule comes after the .yui-gc div.first rule in the src and clobbers it.  The result is that the columns are arranged 1/3, 2/3 instead of 2/3, 1/3 like they should be.

[image]

The simplest (as hacky as it may be) way to fix would to just put in an inline declaration to put the column widths back to where they should be.

```
<div class="yui-gc">
<div class="yui-gd first">
    <div class="yui-u first">reasons</div>
    <div class="yui-u yui-gc">
        <div class="yui-u first" style="width: 66%;">questions</div>
        <div class="yui-u" style="width: 32%;">answers</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="yui-u yui-g">
    <div class="yui-u first">Related</div>
    <div class="yui-u">Product</div>
</div>
```